# Accessing DataStore from ComputeEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When do you think Google will let ComputeEngine VM talk to DataStore?

ComputeEngine instance is so much cheaper compared to AppEngine backend. Maybe this is the reason why they don't want to support it. Thoughts?

Comment: Now available at https://developers.google.com/datastore/ :)

Answer (score 1):

We think that this use case is very important. However, we don't have any ETA for that. Please stay tuned!

Comment: This is how Google can win over people from AWS. There is no noSQL implementation that can compare with DataStore, not mongoDB, not dynamoDB, not HBase, not Riak, not Cassandra, none that comes close to the feature sets of DataStore. And if we can couple DataStore with the flexibility of the *nix virtual machines, then Google cloud will become a VIABLE solution overnight! Please tell me that someone from Google is working on this integration.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence. Please *do* stay tuned!!

Comment: It's available now! https://developers.google.com/datastore/